# Oracle different table's triggers order

Tags: oracle, triggers

I have two triggers: 
One of them:

```
create or replace
TRIGGER bl_process_type_updated
before update
ON bl
REFERENCING NEW AS NEW OLD AS OLD
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN 
    :new.process_type := 'UPDATED';
EXCEPTION    
 WHEN OTHERS THEN  
 NULL; 
 END;
```

Another one:

```
create or replace
TRIGGER bl_process_type_deleted
after insert or update
ON ot
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
    building_id bl.bl_id%TYPE;
BEGIN 
   building_id := :new.bl_id ;
   if(:new.status = 'Sold' or :new.status = 'LeaseTerminated') then
      update bl set process_type='DELETED' where bl_id = building_id;
    end if;
 EXCEPTION    
 WHEN OTHERS THEN  
 NULL; 
 END;
```

Both of triggers update `bl` table's process_type column. If I update `ot` table, `bl` table's trigger fire last so process_type's value is UPDATED but I want that when `ot` table is updated or inserted, `ot` table's trigger fire last and process_type value will be DELETED.

How can I achieve that?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17694591/330315

Comment: The Oracle 11g trigger syntax now includes the FOLLOWS clause to guarantee execution order for triggers defined with the same timing point. But my triggers timing points are different.

Comment: The FOLLOWS clause is not applicable here because the triggers are on different tables, as well as being at different timing points.

Answer (score 1):

I would have started with @Thomas's solution, but based on your subsequent comment, it is clear that presently you have no reliable way for the `bl` table to know whether `process_type` should be set to UPDATED or left DELETED.

Therefore, you probably need to build some means by which `ot` can tell `bl` that the row is to be left as DELETED.

Firstly, don't try to affect the order in which triggers fire - you'll only get yourself into a knot.

One option would be to abandon the idea of using triggers entirely - i.e. create an API (PL/SQL package) that performs inserts & updates on these tables, and handles the subsequent logic that you need. Obviously you'll need to modify your application to use the API. A simple way to make this easy is to put views in front of the tables, along with Instead Of triggers to call the API.

Another option is to put a condition in the `bl_process_type_updated` trigger that switches it off if the update came from the `bl_process_type_deleted` trigger. The switch would have to live in a database package, e.g.:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE bl_trigger_pkg AS
  bl_trigger_enabled BOOLEAN := TRUE;
END;
/

create or replace
TRIGGER bl_process_type_updated
  before update
  ON bl
  REFERENCING NEW AS NEW OLD AS OLD
  FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN 
  IF bl_trigger_pkg.bl_trigger_enabled THEN
    :new.process_type := 'UPDATED';
  END IF;
END;

create or replace
TRIGGER bl_process_type_deleted
  after insert or update
  ON ot
  FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
   building_id bl.bl_id%TYPE;
BEGIN 
   building_id := :new.bl_id ;
   if(:new.status = 'Sold' or :new.status = 'LeaseTerminated') then
      bl_trigger_pkg.bl_trigger_enabled := FALSE;
      update bl set process_type='DELETED' where bl_id = building_id;
      bl_trigger_pkg.bl_trigger_enabled := TRUE;
   end if;
END;
```

By the way, you have to get rid of the `WHEN OTHERS THEN NULL;` bits. You should never just hide all exceptions.

Comment: After 10 years i found this answer which really helped me.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You could do the following:

```
create or replace TRIGGER bl_process_type_updated
before update
ON bl
REFERENCING NEW AS NEW OLD AS OLD
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN 
    if :new.process_type <> 'DELETED' then
        :new.process_type := 'UPDATED';
    end if;
EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN  
    NULL; 
END;
```

Comment: Sorry, I had a typo.  Try it now.

Comment: It works but if a record marked as DELETED, it will never be UPDATED. This status frequently change between DELETED and UPDATED. It is a temporary solution.