# Order of firing before insert triggers in Oracle

Tags: oracle, triggers

I have a table and 2 or more `after Insert Or Update/BEFORE-EACH-ROW triggers` on same table.
Can you tell me what will be the order of firing after insert triggers?

```
TRG_SALE_PRICE  BEFORE EACH ROW VALID   ENABLED INSERT OR UPDATE    ADMIN       427  
TRG_SALE_DATE   BEFORE EACH ROW VALID   ENABLED INSERT OR UPDATE    ADMIN       428
```

Comment: If the order is important maybe you can join the trigger code into one trigger. Based on the names however, it looks like the triggers each operate on a single value and the order should be of no consequence.
I don't think the order of the triggers is in any way determined.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17693502/order-of-execution-of-trigger-and-statements-in-oracle-stored-procedure

Comment: You're right - it's a duplicate.  Deleting my answer.

Comment: the question I want to ask is different.

Comment: i don ask defualt order of triggers. i aksed "what will be order of firing that same type triggers on same table.  
i have Customer table and 2 update trigger(A,B).

Comment: SELECT * FROM SYS.ALL_TRIGGERS where OWNER='SMS' AND TRIGGER_NAME LIKE 'TRG_SALE_%'; First row, first run.